# Is it possible to train a classifier through comparison examples?

Tags: machine-learning, training-data

I'm looking for an ML algorithm that can learn through comparison examples

I make a practical example:

I have 4 numbers in input, which represent the color I see on the monitor

Maybe these numbers are in CMYK format, but it's not important.
The beauty of machine learning is just this:
do something, without knowing what the incoming numbers are

The output I want is the percentage of how much the input color approaches the green

I've seen dozens of examples,
where they advise to solve the problem using
machine learning supervised classification

Then prepare a training table of this type:

```
color               x1  x2  x3  x4  y1
White               .   .   .   .   0
very light green    .   .   .   .   0.3
light green         .   .   .   .   0.6
Green               .   .   .   .   1
```

After that my cluster will be able to process the percentage of green:

Perfect! The output I want is just this:

A percentage estimate of how much the 4 numbers x1..4 are approaching my goal y1 (green)

My problem is that I am not able to build the training in that way.

The data in my possession for the training are comparisons between 2 measures.

Eg

Between light green and light green, you have to choose light green

Assuming this convention:

```
light green:          {a1, a2, a3, a4}
very light green:     {b1, b2, b3, b4}
y:
                       0 = NO this is not good;
                       1 = YES, choose this !!!
```

I could provide the training of data made in this way:

```
[  
  {  b1, b2, b3, b4,  0  },
  {  a1, a2, a3, a4,  1  }
]
```

Can you help me?

Is it possible to train a classifier through comparison examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your training set should have 8 features **x1**, ..., **x8**. From each comparison pair of the form

> [ {b1, b2, b3, b4, 0}, {a1, a2, a3, a4, 1} ]

you can extract two samples of training data as follows:

> **x1**  **x2**  **x3**  **x4**  **x5**  **x6**  **x7**  **x8**  **y**
>   b1  b2  b3  b4  a1  a2  a3  a4  0
>   a1  a2  a3  a4  b1  b2  b3  b4  1

Repeat this process for each pair of comparisons and you will get the full training set. Then you can train your classifier on it.

A prediction value (probability of the classifier) on an unknown comparison pair can be interpreted as the probability that the color corresponding to the first 4 features is closer to the green color compared to the color corresponding to the last 4 features.

The above assumes that **x1**, ..., **x4** and **x5**, ..., **x8** use the same representation.

Comment: Interesting idea. I will do some tests